# Equation for a raindrop falling on a puddle for a mechanical art project

Tags: waves, water

Given a raindrop falling on a puddle, is there an equation that describes the resulting motion?

I found this [article](https://theconversation.com/what-happens-when-a-raindrop-hits-a-puddle-115984) that describes it well, so I was thinking it could be

$$z = \frac{A\sin(kx+wt)}{x}$$ rotated around the z-axis. However I'm not sure how I could verify this.

Could the wave equation also work for this?

$$ \frac{\partial^{2}z}{\partial t^2} = c^2 \left(\frac{\partial^{2}z}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^{2}z}{\partial y^2} \right )$$

The background for this question is I'm working on simulating water waves using motors
connected to tiles for an art project. I want to understand how the continuous displacement of water translates into discrete instructions for servo motors. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing is a very simple model, where a drop is considered a point-like (1) and instantaneous (2) perturbation, and the resulting waves are treated as two-dimensional surface waves (3) (although there may be also waves going into the depth).

Provided that we agree to use all these approximations, you still cannot simply rotate a plane wave solution, but rather need to use the wave equations in [polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator#Two_dimensions). More specifically, the right-hand side of your equation becomes:
$$
\nabla^2 z(x,y)=\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y^2}=
\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial r^2} + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial r}+
\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial \theta^2},
$$
and the solution will be in terms of Bessel functions (the books by Abramovitz&Stegun and Gradshtein&Ryzhik are comprehensive references on Bessel functions, although the basics can be found in the books on electricity&Magnetism or Quantum mechanics).

Comment: Due to symmetry, isn't it so that $\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial \theta^2}=0$?

Comment: @Gert yes, indeed.

Comment: Looking at various *shallow water* wave models, just applying the generic wave equation (in polar coordinates or not) here is probably hopelessly simplistic.

Comment: $\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial r}$ is of course incorrect.

Comment: @Gert it is an art project, it seems. But, if you want to write a deeper answer about the drop model, I would be interested.

Comment: In fact the wave equation in polar coordinates should be: $z_t=c^2\left(z_{rr}+\frac{2}{r}z_r\right)$

Answer (score 1):

The wave equation in polar coordinates is (in PDE shorthand):
$$z_t=c^2\left(z_{rr}+\frac{2z_r}{r}\right)\tag{1}$$
So we're looking for a function $z(r,t)$, which we assume ('Ansatz') to be of the form:
$$z(r,t)=R(r)T(t)$$
Inserting into $(1)$ and reworking gives:
$$\frac{1}{c^2}RT'=TR''+\frac{2}{r}TR'$$
$$\frac{T'}{c^2T}=\frac{R''}{R}+\frac{2R'}{rR}=-k^2$$
where $-k^2$ is a separation constant (a Real Number). This gives us two ODEs:
$$\frac{T'}{c^2T}=-k^2\tag{2}$$
$$\frac{R''}{R}+\frac{2R'}{rR}=-k^2\tag{3}$$
$(3)$ reworked gives
$$rR''+2R'+k^2rR=0$$
Now substitute and insert:
$$\rho(r)=rR(r)$$
$$\rho'=R+rR'$$
$$\rho''=2R'+rR''$$
$$\rho''(r)+k^2\rho(r)=0$$
To get:
$$\rho(r)=c_1\sin kr+c_2\cos kr$$
And:
$$R(r)=\frac{c_1\sin kr}{r}+\frac{c_2\cos kr}{r}$$
Now note that:
$$\lim_{r \to 0}\left[\frac{c_2\cos kr}{r}\right] \to +\infty \Rightarrow c_2=0$$
So that:
$$R(r)=\frac{c_1\sin kr}{r}$$
Solving $(2)$ is easy:
$$\frac{T'}{c^2T}=-k^2$$
$$T(t)=c_3\exp\left(-c^2k^2 t\right)$$
So that we can write:

$$z(r,t)=B\exp\left(-c^2k^2 t\right)\frac{\sin kr}{r}$$

---

Now, in order to determine both $B$ and $k$ we need an initial condition (IC, $t=0$) and a boundary condition (BC).

For IC we could use a sharp, Gaussian-style $z(r,0)=f(0)$ function.

But finding a suitable BC is harder. From the OP's dispersion graphs, we can see that $z(0,t)=0$ which means:

$$R(0)=0$$

Unfortunately that doesn't work because:

$$\lim_{r\to 0}\left[\frac{\sin kr}{r}\right]=k$$

and not zero.